# Complex moments of a random variable

Tags: probability

Do complex moments of a random variable exist? That is, if $X$ is a positive random variable and $m$ denotes its $m$th moment, which is a complex number, can we calculate $\mathbb{E}(X^m)$?

Comment: I do not know if it has any meaning whatsoever, but one can always use the formula for the expected value and just raise $X $ to $b $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Note that when $X > 0$, $|X^b| = X^{\text{Re}(b)}$.  The function $t \to t^b$ is measurable on $(0,\infty)$.  As long as $\mathbb E\left[ X^{\text{Re}(b)}\right] < \infty$, $\mathbb E\left[X^b\right]$ exists, and can be computed using the usual formula.